# How do I use an enum as array element?

Tags: rust

I was a bit surprised that this code would not compile. Being new to Rust, it is possible I did some silly error of course...

```
mod board {
    enum Square {
        Empty,
        Black,
        White
    }

    fn init () -> [Square;9] {
        [Square::Empty; 9]
    }
}
```

> main.rs:10:9: 10:27 error: the trait `core::marker::Copy` is not implemented for
>    the type `board::Square` [E0277]
>   main.rs:10         [Square::Empty; 9]

Or is it a language non-feature that enums are not allowed as array element type?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The array initialization syntax `[T; N]` requires that `T` implements `Copy`, so that it can copy the provided value into each position in the array.

This works:

```rust
mod board {
    #[derive(Copy, Clone)]
    enum Square {
        Empty,
        Black,
        White,
    }

    fn init() -> [Square; 9] {
        [Square::Empty; 9]
    }
}
```